# Proof that When all the sides of two triangles are congruent, the angles of those triangles must also be congruent (Side-Side-Side Congruence)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am studying triangle congruence. It is a very basic subject and maybe because of that I am having a very hard time finding more rigorous explanations. I am specifically interested in the **Side-Side-Side Congruence**.

I know that ["When all the sides of two triangles are congruent, the angles of those triangles must also be congruent"](https://www.sparknotes.com/math/geometry2/congruence/section2/#:%7E:text=The%20simplest%20way%20to%20prove,side%2C%20or%20SSS%20for%20short.). But I can not find a proof for that. Can anyone provide me a proof?

Comment: All sides congruent makes the whole triangles congruent. Thus the angles are, too.

Comment: https://gogeometry.com/geometry/euclid_elements_book_i_8_congruence_sss.htm & https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/SSS.shtml & text books about basic trigonometry

Comment: Not so simple , @eyeballfrog , that logic breaks down when you consider that we can have non-congruent quadrilaterals (or pentagons) with non-congruent angles ; the triangle case is true but requires Proof

Comment: @Prem I thought SSS for triangles was a given here.

Comment: Yes, SSS is for triangles, but we have to give Proof to show that "SSS implies **angle** congruence" , not simply make that claim without Proof. If we can make that claim, then what stops us from making that claim for Quadrilaterals & Pentagons ? @eyeballfrog , We know it is true for triangles because somebody has given Proof. We can not just assume it is true !

Comment: Here is your "Proof" in general case **"All sides congruent makes the whole triangles (Quadtrilaterals/Pentagons) congruent. Thus the angles are, too."** : What is wrong with that "Proof" ? Oh , you say it is true only for triangles ? Then what is the Proof that it is true for triangles ? That Proof is what my two references try to give !! @eyeballfrog

Comment: Let triangles ABC and DEF have congruent corresponding sides. Let draw triangle AGC congruent to DEF in the same semiplane as ABC with respect to line AC. Then AB=AG, BC=GC. Let suppose that B and G are distinct points. Then triangle ABG is isosceles and triangle CBG is isosceles. Then A is on perpendicular bisector of BG and C is on perpendicular bisector of BG. Then perpendicular bisector of BG has two distinct common points with line AC which is impossible. Then our suppose is wrong. Then B and G is the same point. Then triangle ABC is the same as AGC which is congruent to DEF.

Comment: Do you want a proof of SSS congruence? But which axioms and theorems do you allow? Without knowing that, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: In most high school geometry books (eg. Moise & Downs), SAS is usually assumed as a postulate.  Once that is assumed then SSS, ASA, SAA can be proved from that.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, I would be satisfied with any proof. Both answers so far were enough to satisfy my curiosity, but I would welcome other proofs and your perspective. To offer some context: I am a math graduate (second year) and I need to teach a small class on triangles for a interview for an internship at a high school. They definitely are not going to be very rigorous with the proofs, but as I am preparing I got curious, because I have learnt congruence more like as a rule when I was young and never took the time to question why it works until today.

Comment: I agree with the comment written above by mrtwhs. In that case, however, Euclid's proof is not viable. See the page already suggested above for a review of various proofs: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/SSS.shtml

Comment: And I would never use cosine law to prove SSS, see my comment below that answer.

Answer (score 4):

Euclid, Book I, Proposition 8:

> If two triangles have the two sides equal to two sides
> respectively, and also have the base equal to the base, then they also
> have the angles equal which are contained by the equal straight lines.

[image]

> Let ABC and DEF be two triangles having the two sides AB and AC equal
> to the two sides DE and DF respectively, namely AB equal to DE and AC
> equal to DF, and let them have the base BC equal to the base EF.
>
> I say that the angle BAC also equals the angle EDF.
>
> If the triangle ABC is applied to the triangle DEF, and if the point B
> is placed on the point E and the straight line BC on EF, then the
> point C also coincides with F, because BC equals EF.
>
> Then, BC coinciding with EF, therefore BA and AC also coincide with ED
> and DF, for, if the base BC coincides with the base EF, and the sides
> BA and AC do not coincide with ED and DF but fall beside them as EG
> and GF, then given two straight lines constructed on a straight line
> and meeting in a point, there will have been constructed on the same
> straight line and on the same side of it, two other straight lines
> meeting in another point and equal to the former two respectively,
> namely each to that which has the same end with it.
>
> But they cannot be so constructed.
>
> Therefore it is not possible that, if the base BC is applied to the
> base EF, the sides BA and AC do not coincide with ED and DF. Therefore
> they coincide, so that the angle BAC coincides with the angle EDF, and
> equals it.
>
> Therefore if two triangles have the two sides equal to two sides
> respectively, and also have the base equal to the base, then they also
> have the angles equal which are contained by the equal straight lines.
> Q.E.D.

[http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI8.html](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/propI8.html)

Answer (score 3):

The angles of a triangle are uniquely determined by the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) if you know all the side lengths. Have a look [at this forum post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292935/how-do-i-find-the-angles-of-a-triangle-if-i-only-have-the-lengths-of-the-sides).

So, two triangles with equal side lengths also have have identical angles.

Comment: Using the law of cosines to prove SSS works only if SSS was not used is the proof of the law, or in the theorems used in that proof. Can you guarantee that?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#Proofs . There are several proofs, none of which use triangle congruence theorems, as far as I can tell. (In fact, you can derive all geometric properties of trigonometric functions without proving Euclid's theorems, but from set theory or the Peano axioms.) Of course, the Euclidian proof posted by Ethan Bolker is far more elegant than mine since it does not need any trigonometric functions or set theory.

Comment: One of the proofs on that page you linked is indeed [Euclid's proof](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookII/propII12.html). One could start from there and go back through the various theorems used in the proofs, to see if SSS is used or not. But even if it isn't, I would not recommend proving SSS with the law of cosines. Because SSS is a basic tool, needed since the beginning of a Geometry course, while trigonometry is a more advanced topic.